# Django - using HTML href to link to another view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

In my home page i have 2 links that i would like to bring the user to different pages. How would i make the href link to a view i have created in views.py? Putting in the html file name in as the href and clicking it  would make the url in the search bar appear as `/qualifications/qualifications.html` when i want it to be `/qualifications/`

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="qualifications.html">Qualifications</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
```

views.py

```
def qualifications(request):
    context = {"title": "Qualifications"}
    return render(request, "myApp/qualifications.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("qualifications/", views.qualifications, name="qualifications"),
]
```

Comment: The issue  with double `qualifications` is because of using relative URLs. Leading `/` would fix. But there is a major flaw in this solution and @Balizok's answer shows much better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to your views, not your templates. To do that, your href should be under the form `{% url 'your_view_name' %}`.

So in your case the end result would be something like that :

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'qualifications' %}">Qualifications</a></li>         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that if you defined an `app_name` in your `urls.py`, your href would then be `{% url 'your_app_name:your_view_name' %}`.

Answer (score 0):

We write the rest of the address without considering the main root:
Example:127.0.0.1:8000/course_list/detail/id

#x is a key context name in view
<a href="/course_list/detail/{{x.id}}>{{x}}